# Get the individual answer from a sql count() into php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a sql database where I request the following bit of code;
`SELECT albumtype, COUNT(*) FROM albumdata GROUP BY albumtype`

The response in phpMyAdmin is the following table

- albumtype | COUNT(*)
- Album | 4
- EP | 1
- Single | 1

Then I have in my php file the following code that will return the complete count (6).

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT albumtype, COUNT(*) FROM albumdata GROUP BY albumtype');
$stmt->execute() or die("Invalid query");
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

I used this code on another page, but now I want to select a specific part of the "count()" table.

I tried to display a single result with `$row_cnt = $row['Album'];`, but as it turns out, this returns "Array" for some reason. Here is my php call:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT albumtype, COUNT(*) FROM albumdata GROUP BY albumtype');
$stmt->execute() or die("Invalid query");
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$row_cnt = $row['Album'];
```

How can I grab a single row, for example the number of how much the database could find Album (4 times) and put it in a php variable? I tried searching it on here, but didn't get any further.

Comment: You mean `$row['Album'];` instead of `$row;['Album'];` ?

Comment: yif the column name is albumtype   you can get the content as $row['albumtype'];

Comment: wariostarx  please check the answer below and let us know worked or not?

Comment: Sorry, I was not in a position to work on it today, will check tomorrow. And yes, I ment `$row['Album']`, will edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.If you want only specific `albumType` ten you can directly change your query like this:-***

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT albumtype, COUNT(*) as counts FROM albumdata WHERE albumtype = 'Album'");
$stmt->execute() or die("Invalid query");
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$album_cnt = $row['counts'];
echo $album_cnt;
```

***But if you want all then,you need to do it like below:-***

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT albumtype, COUNT(*) as counts FROM albumdata GROUP BY albumtype');
$stmt->execute() or die("Invalid query");
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row_cnt = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $row_cnt[$row['albumtype']] = $row['counts'];
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($row_cnt); 
// you have all data in array so you can use it now like below

foreach($row_cnt as $key=>$value){
  echo "Album type ".$key." has ".$value." counts"."<br/>";
}

//form this all data if you want to compare specific albumType then do like below:-

foreach ($row_cnt as $key=>$value) {
    if($key == 'Album'){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the first code and it seems to work good. I will check on it once the database starts expanding, but I'm guessing it will always work. I will also look if I need the second code anywhere in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the rows till you match the type you want to display:

```
foreach ($row as $srow) {
    if($srow['albumtype'] == 'Album'){
        print $srow['count'];
    }
}
```